# Is philosophy of language on-topic?

Tags: discussion, tags, on-topic-off-topic

Philosophical semantics also.

They are both related with philosophy and the language.

I see that [philosophy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy) tag is used only 2 times but they are not related with philosophy of language actually.

Does acceptability depend on the question? Is there any accepted example?

Or would it be better to ask on philosophy.stackexchange?

Side question: When would it be appropriate to use [philosophy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy) tag?

Comment: You'll probably get better responses at philosophy.stackexchange.com or linguistics.stackexchange.com Such questions are not strictly off topic but just may get responses in a direction that you'd prefer at those other sites.

Comment: I just realized that philosophy stackexchange has philosophy-of-language tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no sharp line separating the present-day philosophy of language from linguistics. Some of the theories developed by the philosophers of language, over the last hundred years or so, can illuminate many specific problems concerning English language and usage. The questions that concern **application** of such philosophical theories to **specific** problems of **English** language should thus be welcomed here, and, in fact, have been welcomed.

On the other hand, the questions that concern the theories of the philosophy of language in the abstract (the questions that could be asked about any language), are probably better asked at some other site, such as the Philosophy Stack Exchange.

For example, a question that involves the application of Gricean maxims to a particular locution is probably within the scope of this site. On the other hand, a question that calls for an interpretation of Heidegger's thesis that the language is the house of being would be off topic here.

It should be noted the questioners may not be aware whether their questions involve philosophy of language. The questioner may sometimes be simply puzzled by some feature of the language, and it is only in answering it that the philosophical undercurrents of that puzzlement become explicit. For example, the questioner may have never heard of Gricean maxims, but they may turn out to play the crucial role in a good answer to it.

Comment: Then where does a non-sourced, largely philosophical answer like this site within the site? https://english.stackexchange.com/a/249055/603

Answer (score 0):

No, but the language of philosophy is on topic ;)

Comment: Only to an extent. Jargon questions are usually better asked at their respective sites.

Comment: @curiousdannii Fair